# Как согласуется уступительное значение союза "хотя" с семантикой глагола "хотеть"?

Tags: этимология, союзы, история

Происхождение союза «хотя» понятно – это деепричастная форма глагола *хотеть*.

В  собственно-противительном значении он синонимичен союзу «несмотря на» (тоже, кстати,  деепричастной форме), но  значение этого союза очевидно, например:

(1) ***Несмотря на** дождь, мы пошли на  прогулку. – Мы **не посмотрели на** дождь  (не приняли его во внимание) и пошли на прогулку.* (2) *Хотя шел дождь, мы пошли на прогулку.*

Каким образом глагол ***хотеть*** (со значением ***желать***)  «присутствует»  в  союзе хотя? Можно ли как-то перестроить предложение, чтобы это было понятно?

Или у союза «хотя» **другая история**, но **какая**?

Comment: (только гипотеза) От большого хотения (а тогда шёл дождь) мы пошли на прогулку. (Охота пуще препятствия)

Comment: Так хотели,  что на дождь не посмотрели?

Comment: Да, примерно так. А дальше могло распространиться на случаи без прямого "хотения".

Comment: Всё замечательно, но вот метка "желания и намерения" относится к придаточному, а там говорится только о дожде. А  в  каких-нибудь источниках подобная информация вам не встречалась? Я опасаюсь, что все наши  гипотезы будут названы "народной этимологией", а это очень "плохое" слово.

Comment: Нет, это я от себя предположил происхождение. Не знаю, озадачиваются ли им в трудах; вот обширная статья о пяти страницах, со списком литературы (там больше о функциях союза и его месте в классификации). http://www.labslsl.ru/?p=909

Comment: Спасибо, Alex_ander, прочитаю обязательно.